# Why C++ 11 added operator bool to the ios classes

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream

In C++ 98, there is a public function in ios classes defined as

```
operator void*() const;
```

An `operator bool` is added in C++11 to the class, that is

```
explicit operator bool() const;
```

From reading the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/), it is not clear to me why the `operator bool` is necessary.

Can anyone gives an example where `operator void*` causes problems, while `operator bool` works just fine?

Comment: Because it's more true to the way these operators are used in *conditions*?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude none other reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++98 there were no `explicit` cast operators so if you had an `operator bool` it meant that the object could be used as a `bool` or anything that can be cast from `bool` (such as `int`) this meant that you could accidentally use your objects in ways that you wouldn't expect or want (such as `obj + 2`). Some objects provided a cast to `void*` which meant that the object could be tested in an `if` statement (not null) but would not be passable to functions expecting `int` etc.

With the introduction of `explicit` cast operators this is no longer needed and in order to have a *testable* object it's much better to use `explicit operator bool` than `operator void*`.

Answer (score 3):

A `void*` is still not a perfect replacement to the shortcomings of an implicit conversion to `bool`. It suffers from the same problem as the conversion to `bool` did, chiefly that some operators allow classes to convert into a pointer before applying the operation.

One glorious example is that with `void*` operator, you could do something like `delete std::cin;`, and it will probably build without a warning, only to cause a failure at run-time. That's probably not code that's *likely* to be written, but it's still desirable to prevent it if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

It boils down to convenience and even a bit of "sponsorship" of new features from the library classes.

The `void*` conversion is dangerous because it can potentially be applied everywhere. Ok, in practice, since it's a pointer and you are probably going to use it in numeric espressions (mainly in conditions) it is kind of safe, but there is potential for trouble if someone try to use it anywhere else. As a class designer, you want to avoid it as much as possible.

In C++11, when you define `explicit` operator, you should keep in mind that, for what concerns us, the `explicit` part is ignored in a condition. So you are greatly narrowing the potential for unwanted conversions and then unwanted results. Outside of a condition, there will be no conversion and so a compile time error will warn you of a potential misuse of the class (that you can still willingly allow with proper cast).

Comment: I would contend that an `if` is explicitly *not* a numeric context. The reason for `explicit bool` includes *preventing* arithmetic